# What makes is the difference between a tree and a graph?

Tags: graphs, data-structures, trees

I have seen in some text books that they have started talking about a tree and then they use the terms such as vertices and edges and treat is as a graph.

What makes a graph a graph and what makes a tree a tree?
I am getting the impression that a tree is a subset of a graph but what are these properties that make a graph a tree?

Is there a way to classify a graph from a tree?

Comment: Trees are connected Graphs without cycles.

Comment: Did you have a look on Wikipedia?

Comment: is that it? what about the type of edges they have? Are cross edges allowed? Can one node have two parents?

Comment: You can always draw a tree without crossings. And yes a node may have more than a single parent. You can also think of (connected) trees as any graphs of |V|+1 edges, where |V| is the number of vertices.

Comment: "a node can have more than a single parent" is that for trees?

Comment: p.s. where does the +1 edge go ? :)

Comment: @jgyou You mean $|V|-1$ edges.

Comment: @user1932405 A cycle in graph theory might mean something else than what you think; consult [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory)).

Comment: @user1932405 I think that if you'd *read* all these books you would not have to ask these questions. Which books have you looked into? Which definitions of graph and tree do they use? Which parts make you confused about how trees and graphs relate? Are you interested in graph-theoretic or data-structures terminology/definitions?

Comment: @Yuval Filmus Yes, sorry, my mistake. It's -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An *unrooted* tree is a connected acyclic graph, that is a graph in which any two vertices are connected, and which contains no cycles. In particular, it's a graph.

A *rooted* tree is a tree in which one of the vertices has been designated as *root*. Every other vertex has a *parent*, which is its unique neighbor closer to the root. Its other neighbors are known as its *children*.

Comment: can you please clarify what kind of edges a tree and a graph can have? Also by your definition of "unique neighbour" does that mean that tree children must have a single unique parent?

Comment: Yes, but I bet that [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)) did a better job. In short, though, a graph is specified by a set of vertices, and for every two vertices $x,y$, whether the edge $(x,y)$ exists or not. That's all. Graphs do not come with any kind of drawing.

Comment: yes thats fine but what I mean is tree-edges, back-edges and cross-edges I was under the impression you could only have tree edges in a tree, is that true?

Comment: This terminology comes from the DFS algorithm, and describes its output. DFS indeed finds a *spanning* tree in every connected graph. A tree would indeed have only tree-edges in the classification produced by DFS.

Comment: so if you do a DFS search on a graph and you only get tree-edges that means that your graph is a tree? Otherwise if you get any other type of edge, it is not a tree?

Comment: Right, a connected graph is a tree if DFS only finds tree-edges.